# using a dictionary in django view

Tags: python, database, django, dictionary

In my django app,I need to create a mapping between a username and a filename.When a user selects a particular file ,the program would associate a mapping between that username and the filename.

To use a python dictionary,I tried as follows:

```
views.py
----------

uname_file_map ={}

def user_select_file(request):
    filename = get_filename_from_request()
    username = request.user.username
    uname_file_map[username] = filename
    ....

def do_some_file_ops(request):
   username = request.user.username
   process_file_contents(uname_file_map.get(username))
   ...
```

It works without any problem when I use two browsers(`chrome and firefox`) , login as two different users and select two different files. What I am wondering is,will this break if many users login at the same time and select different files,since the same dictionary instance is used by all.

Is using two `database` tables `User with a filename_id field` and `Filename` a better solution? Or is the dictionary sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a model to achieve what you are looking for ?

```
class FileMapping(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file_name = models.CharField(_('filename'))


def user_select_file(request):
    filename = get_filename_from_request()
    fm = FileMapping(user=request.user, file_name=filename)
    ....

def do_some_file_ops(request):
   fm = FileMapping.objects.filter(user=request.user)
   process_file_contents(fm)
```

I think it is more "django friendly" than using a pure python solution that would need to be checked for several security issues such as concurrence as you mention.

Comment: +1, although `file` is probably a charfield rather than a FK.

Comment: But better not to use "file" as field name, because this is reserved to builtin function. Also original author's example probably wouldn't work properly if server would use several processes to serve requests and wouldn't persist any work results between restarts.

Answer (score 2):

> It works without any problem when I use two browsers(chrome and firefox) , login as two different users and select two different files.

s/it works/it seems to work/

As long as you're running this code on a single-threaded / single-process server, AND the process is not restarted, it "kind-of" work if what you want is non-persistant mapping with a single file per user at a given time and you just don't care what file you're going to process at any given time.

This will totally break as soon as you deploy your code in a multithreaded or multi-process environment.

IOW : do as Martin said, use models ;)